Estilos SCSS no cargan la primera vez que visito una página en Next.js
Estoy haciendo una pequeña página de delivery de comida local. Cuando ingreso al detalle de un restaurante, desde la página de "todos los restaurantes", los estilos no cargan y la página se muestra desordenada:

Sin embargo, si yo recargo la página con Ctrl + R o F5, mágicamente los estilos ahora sí son importados:

Los estilos los estoy importando como módulos SCSS: import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?
Estoy usando estas versiones:

Next.js: 14.2.1
Sass/Scss: 1.75.0

Dejo el archivo page.tsx y el styles.module.scss por si sirve de algo revisarlo
page.tsx
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import useGlobalSettings from "@/hooks/useGlobalSettings";
import useBusiness, { TFood } from "@/hooks/useBusiness";
import {
  Tab,
  Box,
  Tabs,
  Modal,
  IconButton,
  Typography,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemButton,
  List as MUIList,
} from "@mui/material";
import CallMadeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CallMade";
import CallIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Call";
import CloseIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Close";
import ShoppingCartIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart";
import FoodCard from "@/components/FoodCard";
import List from "@/components/List";
import Counter from "@/components/Counter";
import ColoredButton from "@/components/ColoredButton";
import { API_URL } from "@/utils/consts";
import useShoppingCart from "@/hooks/useShoppingCart";

import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

export default function NegocioPage() {
  const { slug } = useParams<{ slug: string }>();
  const { business, businessLoading } = useBusiness(slug);
  const [firstMainFood, setFirstMainFood] = useState<TFood>();
  const [firstSecondFood, setSecondMainFood] = useState<TFood>();
  const [sectionSelected, setSectionSelected] = useState(0);
  const [targetFood, setTargetFood] = useState<TFood>();
  const [targetFoodAmount, setTargetFoodAmount] = useState(1);
  const { setMainStyles } = useGlobalSettings();
  const { setFood } = useShoppingCart();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMainStyles({
      paddingTop: "25px",
    });

    return () => setMainStyles({});
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (businessLoading) return;

    const foodCategoriesLength = business.FoodCategory.length;
    if (
      foodCategoriesLength >= 1 &&
      business.FoodCategory[0].Food.length >= 1
    ) {
      setFirstMainFood(business.FoodCategory[0].Food[0]);
    }

    if (
      foodCategoriesLength >= 2 &&
      business.FoodCategory[1].Food.length >= 2
    ) {
      setSecondMainFood(business.FoodCategory[1].Food[0]);
    }
  }, [businessLoading]);

  function addToShoppingCart() {
    if (targetFood == undefined) return;

    setFood(targetFood, targetFoodAmount, business.id);
    setTargetFood(undefined);
    setTargetFoodAmount(1);
  }

  if (businessLoading) return;
  return (
    <div className={styles.negocio}>
      <div className={styles["business-images"]}>
        <div className={styles["banner-container"]}>
          <Image
            className={styles.banner}
            width={1280}
            height={720}
            src={`${API_URL}/static/banners/${business.banner}`}
            alt="Banner"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
          />
        </div>
        <Image
          className={styles.logo}
          width={600}
          height={600}
          src={`${API_URL}/static/logos/${business.logo}`}
          alt="Logo"
        />
      </div>
      <div className={styles["initial-info"]}>
        <div className={styles["business-data"]}>
          <div className={styles["title-schedule"]}>
            <h1 className={styles.title}>{business.name}</h1>
            <h6 className={styles.schedule}>Horario: 9:00 a.m a 11:30 p.m</h6>
          </div>
          <div className={styles["main-plates"]}>
            {firstMainFood != undefined && (
              <FoodCard
                name={firstMainFood.name}
                imgSrc={`${API_URL}/static/foods/${firstMainFood.img_url}`}
                description={firstMainFood.description}
                onOrderBtnClick={() => setTargetFood(firstMainFood)}
              />
            )}
            {firstSecondFood != undefined && (
              <FoodCard
                name={firstSecondFood.name}
                imgSrc={`${API_URL}/static/foods/${firstSecondFood.img_url}`}
                description={firstSecondFood.description}
                onOrderBtnClick={() => setTargetFood(firstSecondFood)}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles["map-schedules-container"]}>
          <div
            className={styles["map-container"]}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: business.location }}
          ></div>
          <Box>
            <List
              list={[
                "Lunes: 9:00 a.m - 9:00 p.m",
                "Martes: 9:00 a.m - 9:00 p.m",
              ]}
            />
            <CellphoneAsList cellphone={business.phone_number} />
          </Box>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.menu}>
        <h2 className={styles["menu-title"]}>Menú</h2>
        <h4 className={styles["menu-schedule"]}>
          Horario: 9:00 a.m - 11:00 p.m
        </h4>
        <Box>
          <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider", ml: 15 }}>
            <Tabs
              value={sectionSelected}
              onChange={(_, nv) => setSectionSelected(nv)}
              aria-label="basic tabs example"
            >
              {business.FoodCategory.map((fc, i) => (
                <Tab key={i} value={i} label={fc.name} />
              ))}
            </Tabs>
          </Box>
          {business.FoodCategory.map((fc, i) =>
            sectionSelected == i ? (
              <Box
                key={i}
                display="grid"
                gridTemplateColumns="1fr 1fr"
                gap="50px"
                mt={5}
              >
                {fc.Food.map((f, i) => (
                  <FoodCard
                    key={i}
                    name={f.name}
                    description={f.description}
                    imgSrc={`${API_URL}/static/foods/${f.img_url}`}
                    onOrderBtnClick={() => setTargetFood(f)}
                  />
                ))}
              </Box>
            ) : (
              <></>
            )
          )}
        </Box>
      </div>
      <Modal
        open={targetFood != undefined}
        onClose={() => setTargetFood(undefined)}
      >
        <Box
          sx={{
            width: "35%",
            height: "70%",
            bgcolor: "#fff",
            position: "absolute",
            top: "50%",
            left: "50%",
            transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
            p: "20px",
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
        >
          <IconButton onClick={() => setTargetFood(undefined)}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Box
            p="0 15px"
            display="grid"
            gap={1}
            borderBottom="1px solid var(--gray)"
            pb={2}
          >
            <Typography
              fontFamily="inherit"
              component="h2"
              fontSize={25}
              fontWeight="bold"
            >
              {targetFood?.name}
            </Typography>
            <Typography
              fontFamily="inherit"
              component="span"
              fontSize={15}
              color="var(--pink)"
            >
              Precio: ${targetFood?.price}
            </Typography>
            <Typography fontFamily="inherit" component="p" fontSize={15}>
              {targetFood?.description}
            </Typography>
            <Box mt={2}>
              <Image
                src={`${API_URL}/static/foods/${targetFood?.img_url}`}
                alt={targetFood?.name || ""}
                width={200}
                height={200}
                style={{
                  borderRadius: "25px",
                  width: 200,
                  height: "auto",
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                }}
              />
            </Box>
          </Box>
          <Box mt={3} display="flex" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Counter onNumberChange={(n) => setTargetFoodAmount(n)} />
            <ColoredButton color="pink" onClick={addToShoppingCart}>
              <ShoppingCartIcon sx={{ mr: 2 }} /> Agregar al carrito
            </ColoredButton>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

function CellphoneAsList({ cellphone }: { cellphone: string }) {
  return (
    <MUIList sx={{ width: "100%", bgcolor: "var(--white)" }}>
      <ListItemButton>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <CallIcon sx={{ color: "var(--pink)" }} />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
          primary={cellphone}
          sx={{ borderBottom: "2px solid var(--gray)" }}
          primaryTypographyProps={{ sx: { fontWeight: 800 } }}
        />
        <CallMadeIcon sx={{ color: "var(--pink)" }} />
      </ListItemButton>
    </MUIList>
  );
}

styles.module.scss
.negocio {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 75px 150px;

  & :global {
    .css-1h9z7r5-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiTab-root.Mui-selected {
      color: #000000;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .css-1aquho2-MuiTabs-indicator {
      background-color: #000000;
    }
  }

  .business-images {
    position: relative;
    height: 350px;

    .banner-container {
      border-radius: 15px;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .logo {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 150px;
      height: auto;
      transform: translateY(50%);
    }
  }

  .initial-info {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 75% 1fr;
    gap: 35px;

    .business-data {
      padding-top: 100px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      gap: 25px;

      .title-schedule {
        .title {
          font-weight: 700;
          font-size: 50px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .schedule {
          color: var(--gray);
        }
      }

      .main-plates {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        gap: 35px;
      }
    }

    .map-schedules-container {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 25px;
      border-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: var(--white);

      .map-container {
        width: 100%;

        iframe {
          border: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 200px !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .menu {
    margin-top: 50px;

    .menu-title {
      color: var(--pink);
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: 700;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #bbbbbb;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .menu-schedule {
      font-size: 15px;
      color: #bbbbbb;
    }
  }
}

